# Lifecycle hook for retrieving data from Firebase in a Vue component

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuefire

I have a Vue 2 component, which uses Vuefire to bind declaratively with a Firebase realtime database:

```
import { db } from '../firebase/db'
export default {
    data: () => ({
        cats: []
    }),
    firebase: {
        cats: db.ref('cats')
    },
    mounted: function() {
        // loop over this.cats
    }
}
```

I want the component to loop over the `cats` property when it is mounted. The problem is that when it is mounted it has not yet retrieved the cats from the database. Is there a simple way to hook into this point? Or do I have to say goodbye to this neat way of fetching data and do it all in `mounted`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the vuefire documentation for [declarative binding](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#declarative-binding):

> Any Database Reference provided in a `firebase` option will be bound at
> creation (after Vue's `created` hook) to the specified key on the
> component

So you actually don't need to add anything in the `mounted` hook. If you want to trigger an action when the `cats` array is populated, you can use a standard Vue.js `watch`.

---

If you don't want to subscribe to real time changes in the RTDB `cats` ref (i.e. do a *binding* in vuefire vocabulary) and only want to read once the `cats` node data when the component is mounted, you should use the standard Firebase JS SDK, as explained [here](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/querying.html#one-time-read) in the vuefire doc.